# IOS 12 OTP Reading from specific sender

Tags: ios, sms, ios12

In iOS 12 beta version we are able to autoread OTP from SMS in system keyboard.

But we want OS to read OTP from specific sender only not from any sender.

For example while customer is on enter OTP page for app A meanwhile it also receives delayed OTP from app B. Now system keyboard will show OTP from app B also.

Is there any provision to provide SenderId/SenderName while specifying `autocomplete`.

I had gone through apple documentation did not find anything like this.

Please comment if my question is not clear.

Thanks in Advance.

Comment: Hey do u have any solution for this .?